# what messages could be delivered to socket that is only used for sending

Tags: sockets, networking

In our application we have UDP socket(s) that are used only to send packets (these sockets are never read, and never bound to a port). The sockets are "connected" to the destination address.  Are there messages like ICMP etc that could conceivably be directed back at these ports and delivered to the receive buffers of these sockets? If so for what types of messages would this occur?

Answer (score 0):

> (these sockets are never read, and never bound to a port).

They are bound to a port when you call `connect()` if not already bound.

> Are there messages like ICMP etc that could conceivably be directed back at these ports

Yes. ICMP UNREACHABLE for a start.

> and delivered to the receive buffers of these sockets?

No. ICMP UNREACHABLE will cause an exception next time you use the socket.

> If so for what types of messages would this occur?

None. If you are getting data in the socket send buffer, someone is sending you UDP datagrams. In fact the connect target is sending you UDP a datagrams.